# Array Merge/Replace

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
Array
(
    [2005] => 0
    [2006] => 0
    [2007] => 0
    [2008] => 0
    [2009] => 0
)

Array
(
    [2007] => 5
    [2008] => 6.05
    [2009] => 7
)
```

I want to merge these two arrays such that if a value exists in the 2nd array, it overwrites the first array's value.  So the resulting array would be:

```
Array
(
    [2005] => 0
    [2006] => 0
    [2007] => 5
    [2008] => 6.05
    [2009] => 7
)
```

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE:
This was my best attempt, but it's wildly unsuccessful:

```
    $final = '';
    foreach ($years as $k => $v){
        if (in_array($k,$values)){
            $final .= $values[$k] . '|';
        }else{
            $final .= $k[$v] . '|';
        }

    }

    echo "final = $final";
```

Comment: Not to seem like I have sour grapes or anything, but there's no need to write a function for this when PHP already has an operator that does it. See my answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As I've just recently learned, PHP has an [array union operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) that does exactly this:

```
$result = $a + $b;
```

Where $a is the array with the values that you want to take precedence. (So in your example, that means that the second array is "`$a`".

Comment: what if the arrays had empty strings?  this scenario i came across a lot. $result  = array_filter($a) + $b; would remove all the empty strings in $a, then 'merge' it with $b, then rearrange the index with sort()

Comment: I've found a nice image and description explain full difference: https://softonsofa.com/php-array_merge-vs-array_replace-vs-plus-aka-union/

Comment: For reference, it might be important to note that neither this method nor `array_replace()` work as intended with non-associative arrays.

Answer (score 15):

It's that simple:

`$new_array = array_replace(array_1,array_2)`;

[the php manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php)

Comment: I prefer this solution: 1) the function name explains what this code does; 2) the higher priority array is mentioned later.

Comment: This is a nice solutuon, and has a different resut to the accepted answer. In this case, array_1 is the master array, and *maintains the order* of the final array, while the elements for array_2 are distributed over the elements for array_1. The accepted answer keeps the order of array_1 and anything in array_2 that is not in array_1 gets tagged onto the end. Both answers are correct in the strict wording of teh question, but have slightly different use-cases dependin on which array *defines the order* of the elements in the result.

Answer (score 4):

Can't it just be this simple:

```
$new_array = array_unique(array_merge($ar1,$ar2));
```

Maybe I'm missing something or I'm crazy.

Answer (score 3):

i changed that a little bit for inner arrays, 
thanks for your code that is give an idea at first step :)

```
function combine($a1, $a2) {
    foreach($a2 as $k => $v) {
        if(is_array($v)) {
            if(!isset($a1[$k]))
                $a1[$k] = null;

            $a1[$k] = combine($a1[$k], $v);
        } else {
            $a1[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $a1;
}
```

Comment: Though this function isn't even necessary (there's a built-in operator that does this), the whole function could have been written much more concisely as (sorry, can't linebreak): foreach ($a2 as $k => $v) $a1[$k] = $v; return $a1;

Comment: unless the & character before a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with PHP, but something like:

```
foreach ($array2 as $i => $value) {
  $array1[$i] = $value;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing I missed a complexity that you may not have explained in detail in the question.

Comment: +1 - this is definitely the simplest and easiest way to do it